# Are answers being listed in the right order?

Tags: support

Maybe I don't understand Stack, or maybe our listings are broken.

The way I understand it, the accepted answer should be listed first, and the other answers will be listed in order of upvotes.

Check out this [question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/what-is-qi-power-and-has-it-been-proven-to-exist-scientifically)

The accepted answer is indeed on top, and then a highly upvoted post, followed by three posts with negative scores, followed by two posts with positive scores.

Do I misunderstand the listing order or is it broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the answers are sorted by votes, then yes, the accepted is at the top (unless it is a self answer), then the rest by descending score order.

You can also sort the answers by original post age (oldest) and by the latest activity date (activity).